# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - #1452

Tags: database, performance

I am having a few troubles with inserting my old database details into my new database.
Here is what I am trying to insert in my new database from old one.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.7
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: db.dayz.st
-- Generation Time: Jul 05, 2013 at 10:22 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.30-1~dotdeb.0-log
-- PHP Version: 5.4.11-1~dotdeb.0

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `bliss_1294`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `world_vehicle`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `world_vehicle` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vehicle_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `world_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `worldspace` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]',
  `description` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chance` decimal(4,3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `last_modified` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx1_world_vehicle` (`vehicle_id`),
  KEY `idx2_world_vehicle` (`world_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=99466 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `world_vehicle`
--

INSERT INTO `world_vehicle` (`id`, `vehicle_id`, `world_id`, `worldspace`, `description`, `chance`, `last_modified`) VALUES
(565, 29, 10, '[354,[10951,17800.9,0.0223007]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(566, 29, 10, '[162,[10922.9,17345.1,0.0321388]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(567, 81, 10, '[157,[10157.5,19150.1,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(568, 18, 10, '[184,[10339.8,18663.9,0.0126953]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(569, 30, 10, '[340,[10948.5,17206.8,0.0906601]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(570, 3, 10, '[62,[10984.5,18950.9,-4.76837e-007]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(571, 3, 10, '[339,[10270.8,17668.5,0.0456314]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(572, 32, 10, '[204,[11211.6,18116,0.00648117]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(573, 21, 10, '[243,[10228.8,18638.9,0.00063324]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(578, 89, 10, '[327,[11099.5,18673.8,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(579, 14, 10, '[319,[10633.1,17340.5,0.00105286]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(580, 81, 10, '[170,[10117.2,19008.2,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(582, 81, 10, '[95,[10306.9,16804,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(583, 81, 10, '[131,[8788.46,19497.9,0.0118561]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(584, 3, 10, '[349,[11036.6,16840.4,0.0015564]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(585, 58, 10, '[316,[8778.47,19045.2,-0.00346375]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(586, 25, 10, '[92,[11698.8,18823.9,-0.338678]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(587, 25, 10, '[112,[11680.8,18691.2,-0.360215]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(588, 29, 10, '[317,[7474.65,4423.4,-0.00769424]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(589, 29, 10, '[277,[9057.16,2530.97,-0.0063858]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(590, 29, 10, '[134,[9135.33,7964.65,-0.00769043]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(591, 29, 10, '[95,[4019.75,6695.92,-0.00769424]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(592, 29, 10, '[220,[13403,8635.49,-0.00769043]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(593, 29, 10, '[66,[5822.55,8464.95,-0.00753784]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(594, 29, 10, '[56,[12022.2,15220.1,-0.00769806]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(595, 29, 10, '[318,[14163.5,12404.8,-0.00769424]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(596, 29, 10, '[0,[15257.5,9471.55,-0.00769615]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(597, 29, 10, '[70,[17359,7417.03,-0.00769043]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(598, 29, 10, '[189,[12614,11897.5,-0.00769806]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(599, 29, 10, '[57,[16971.7,12787.1,-0.00769615]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(600, 29, 10, '[304,[11371.1,1101.07,-0.00540161]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(601, 81, 10, '[92,[6514.76,8748.42,0.0316048]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(602, 81, 10, '[233,[4727.36,8095.94,7.62939e-006]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(603, 81, 10, '[131,[5224.73,6274.16,0.00038147]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(604, 81, 10, '[131,[10011.1,7181.43,0.00144958]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(605, 81, 10, '[120,[6510.3,5542.96,0.000148773]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(606, 81, 10, '[131,[7768.96,4579.06,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(607, 81, 10, '[320,[13427.7,8644.56,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(608, 81, 10, '[178,[15123.8,9375.95,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(609, 81, 10, '[169,[16213.3,14955.3,0.0228539]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(610, 81, 10, '[45,[7706.79,4174.13,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(611, 81, 10, '[360,[15355.2,9831.41,3.05176e-005]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(612, 81, 10, '[333,[12887.8,13419.6,0.02285]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(613, 81, 10, '[131,[8395.68,3332.51,0.000270844]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(614, 81, 10, '[296,[15925.3,8918.18,0.00468254]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(615, 81, 10, '[131,[14267.7,11740.5,0.00571442]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(616, 81, 10, '[167,[11115.6,16432.1,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(617, 81, 10, '[50,[9682.93,5836.99,0.0102997]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(618, 81, 10, '[147,[10770.1,2291.05,0.00911713]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(619, 81, 10, '[146,[8233.2,3557.05,0.00823021]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(620, 81, 10, '[154,[14631.3,18568.4,0.00568962]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(621, 81, 10, '[357,[15333,16325.5,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(622, 81, 10, '[179,[14983.5,9843.48,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(623, 81, 10, '[131,[11717.7,14820.3,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(624, 81, 10, '[160,[14953.7,17686.2,0.0230598]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(625, 81, 10, '[124,[11765.8,15295.7,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(626, 81, 10, '[193,[16535.6,12305.2,0.0189724]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(627, 81, 10, '[58,[13973.5,12345.3,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(628, 81, 10, '[0,[13233.2,12143.6,0.0196762]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(629, 81, 10, '[183,[17595.4,6287.17,0.00100708]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(630, 81, 10, '[131,[16712.8,8479.33,0.0872345]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(631, 81, 10, '[3,[12873.5,12944.9,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(632, 81, 10, '[143,[15653,10009.4,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(633, 81, 10, '[143,[12961.6,14013.4,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(634, 18, 10, '[132,[7808.4,4330.21,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(635, 18, 10, '[66,[17398.7,6512.27,0.0234985]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(636, 18, 10, '[183,[15569,8258.74,0.141594]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(637, 18, 10, '[158,[17167.2,7767.53,0.0743866]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(638, 18, 10, '[158,[12452.1,14354.7,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(639, 18, 10, '[128,[16412.7,8723.52,0.151649]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(640, 18, 10, '[214,[16459,12013.3,0.00720406]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(641, 18, 10, '[278,[15560.1,16005.2,0.00566101]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(642, 18, 10, '[76,[13169.2,19343.8,0.0113888]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(643, 18, 10, '[158,[11545.9,15615.5,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(644, 18, 10, '[84,[12838.6,11940.6,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(645, 18, 10, '[181,[14907.1,9766.22,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(646, 18, 10, '[158,[17324.2,7421.05,-0.102005]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(647, 18, 10, '[158,[5179.3,8106.45,0.00350952]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(648, 18, 10, '[113,[7495.9,8301.67,0.00138855]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(649, 18, 10, '[128,[9141,8111.72,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(650, 18, 10, '[303,[5915.2,5921.79,1.90735e-005]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(651, 18, 10, '[130,[7652.84,4086.29,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(652, 7, 10, '[203,[10693.7,6536.87,0.0229568]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(653, 9, 10, '[157,[8047.39,8636.07,0.00374603]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(654, 77, 10, '[158,[5482.39,8202.6,0.0140457]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(655, 8, 10, '[349,[5570.72,6114.17,8.7738e-005]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(656, 30, 10, '[318,[6888.35,5214.03,0.00019455]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(657, 30, 10, '[225,[7839.55,4494.92,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(658, 30, 10, '[140,[8652.84,3068.12,0.00364494]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(659, 30, 10, '[128,[7167.82,8533.28,0.00255585]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(660, 30, 10, '[120,[16354.1,13180.9,0.0191612]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(661, 30, 10, '[158,[8211.36,6154.37,0.0160217]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(662, 30, 10, '[208,[9050.35,7881.65,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(663, 30, 10, '[215,[16175.9,10431.5,0.0055275]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(664, 30, 10, '[182,[15113.4,9929.65,0.137263]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(665, 30, 10, '[134,[11133.3,1959.98,0.000549316]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(666, 30, 10, '[144,[8542.64,3162.03,0.000202179]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(667, 30, 10, '[295,[13424,8648.58,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(668, 30, 10, '[179,[15252.8,9215.89,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(669, 77, 10, '[126,[7214.78,4930.56,0.00031662]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(670, 8, 10, '[140,[8275.1,3476.29,0.00530815]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(671, 7, 10, '[271,[16905.2,6272.22,0.00584412]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(672, 77, 10, '[143,[10510.9,2562.58,0.0067749]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(673, 8, 10, '[147,[9604.49,4852.59,0.00148773]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(674, 77, 10, '[91,[11172.7,15990.7,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(675, 8, 10, '[181,[12874.6,13155.3,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(676, 9, 10, '[185,[16062.1,15670.4,0.0116997]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(677, 77, 10, '[180,[16259.6,11102.7,0.0425148]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(678, 8, 10, '[87,[17370.6,7346.27,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(679, 19, 10, '[271,[12152.6,14950.1,0.0159607]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(680, 19, 10, '[311,[12435,15202.6,0.00318909]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(681, 19, 10, '[277,[13670.5,13096.8,0.00578308]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(682, 19, 10, '[222,[13162.4,13622.9,0.00712585]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(683, 19, 10, '[293,[13364.2,13315.5,0.0142212]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(684, 19, 10, '[250,[13268.5,19505.5,0.0949459]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(685, 19, 10, '[332,[12080.8,19157.7,0.0564194]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(686, 19, 10, '[283,[8596.41,19476.3,0.0055542]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(687, 19, 10, '[293,[8411.4,19204.7,0.125671]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(688, 19, 10, '[293,[1663.18,7532.56,0.00292587]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(689, 19, 10, '[2,[2249.73,7592.62,0.0450172]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(690, 19, 10, '[272,[1519.11,7133.55,0.141129]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(691, 19, 10, '[293,[1680.76,6870.38,0.0112076]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(692, 19, 10, '[201,[5554.78,6028.8,3.8147e-005]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(693, 19, 10, '[31,[4594.34,6231.05,0.0142784]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(694, 20, 10, '[315,[7374.36,4759.34,-0.000656128]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(695, 20, 10, '[44,[7710.61,4611.11,-0.000656128]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(696, 20, 10, '[128,[7716.36,3906.45,-0.000656128]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(697, 20, 10, '[274,[13456,8603.68,-0.000671387]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(698, 20, 10, '[2,[14879.6,9330.99,-0.000658035]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(699, 3, 10, '[315,[11508.4,1262.49,0.0632362]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(700, 3, 10, '[330,[9883.54,3139.64,0.0131836]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(701, 3, 10, '[237,[11825,1411.95,0.0010252]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(703, 3, 10, '[134,[13450.8,8605.12,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(704, 3, 10, '[339,[10688.8,11734,0.550781]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(705, 3, 10, '[191,[16826.5,8195.05,0.00675964]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(706, 3, 10, '[184,[15012.4,15616.1,0.00805664]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(707, 3, 10, '[293,[18394.7,5052.93,0.106243]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(708, 3, 10, '[273,[17564.7,6309.81,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(709, 3, 10, '[181,[16446.6,11620.8,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(710, 3, 10, '[293,[13174.2,13260.9,0.0268364]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(711, 3, 10, '[292,[12478,13860,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(712, 3, 10, '[270,[14688.2,10835.4,0.0373383]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(713, 3, 10, '[318,[9711.47,1983.53,0.00771332]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(714, 3, 10, '[25,[5711.09,5851.74,0.0101013]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(715, 3, 10, '[233,[9015.01,7405.48,0.021965]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(716, 3, 10, '[320,[2799.21,7081.33,0.0408325]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(718, 3, 10, '[293,[11398.1,15315.9,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(719, 3, 10, '[293,[15651.9,9659.04,-0.102001]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(720, 3, 10, '[350,[16812.2,6297.74,0.00746155]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(721, 32, 10, '[179,[9082.64,21516.1,0.116533]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(722, 32, 10, '[266,[12963.3,11995.9,0.0131302]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(723, 32, 10, '[293,[3807.23,7246.74,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(724, 32, 10, '[55,[4034.12,7745.7,6.10352e-005]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(725, 32, 10, '[43,[5856.52,8621.12,0.00302887]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(726, 32, 10, '[221,[17118.1,7807.23,0.0652618]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(727, 32, 10, '[91,[15039.7,14824.6,0.00798798]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(729, 32, 10, '[359,[13414.2,8651.67,1.52588e-005]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(730, 32, 10, '[273,[15457.5,9795.01,0.0424709]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(731, 32, 10, '[272,[16283.9,10041.2,0.00337219]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(732, 32, 10, '[2,[16335.7,10544.5,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(733, 32, 10, '[259,[7742.34,7074.12,0.0001297]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(734, 32, 10, '[243,[8374.7,5813.29,0.0271759]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(735, 32, 10, '[181,[16465.9,14267.1,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(736, 32, 10, '[3,[15151.9,9366.48,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(737, 32, 10, '[307,[9534.39,7782.44,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(738, 32, 10, '[293,[11570.2,15115.9,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(739, 32, 10, '[293,[13297.6,12424.3,0.00325775]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(740, 32, 10, '[47,[10099,2944.08,0.0168152]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(742, 32, 10, '[308,[6124.46,5807.65,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(743, 21, 10, '[314,[7756.23,4266.02,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(744, 21, 10, '[271,[2168,7026.63,0.000202179]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(745, 21, 10, '[359,[2129.33,7064.36,0.0020256]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(746, 21, 10, '[275,[16448.8,9219.42,0.146385]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(747, 23, 10, '[293,[15137.8,10164.2,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(748, 90, 10, '[72,[17214.1,5605.34,-0.00038147]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(749, 21, 10, '[293,[17380.9,5111.01,0.0486755]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(750, 21, 10, '[360,[9630.26,4229.79,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(752, 21, 10, '[358,[9628.1,4417.41,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(753, 21, 10, '[151,[16695.3,10633.4,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(754, 21, 10, '[360,[3888.82,6974.72,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(755, 29, 10, '[360,[9303.53,4234.05,-0.00769806]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(756, 29, 10, '[271,[9409.02,4633.06,-0.00769806]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(757, 53, 10, '[293,[6739.95,8450.5,0.00347137]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(763, 55, 10, '[216,[7469.84,8071.2,-0.678246]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(764, 58, 10, '[118,[16014.9,8410.25,0.0563278]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(765, 62, 10, '[137,[9612.94,2065.55,-0.0139961]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(766, 23, 10, '[270,[2167.46,7018.76,0.000156403]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(767, 58, 10, '[266,[3695.45,2348.44,0.293526]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(768, 62, 10, '[293,[4927.72,8571.45,0.0936146]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(769, 23, 10, '[293,[4558.08,6561.13,0.000110626]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(770, 62, 10, '[91,[17374.2,7641.97,-0.0154572]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(771, 23, 10, '[93,[13412.8,8656.76,1.52588e-005]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(772, 58, 10, '[340,[9514.06,4977.89,-0.0154419]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(773, 62, 10, '[216,[14227.3,19121.1,0.0452614]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(774, 23, 10, '[265,[17085,6914.41,0.0455627]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(775, 58, 10, '[129,[6218.76,9814.33,-0.00266266]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(776, 62, 10, '[338,[4092.65,8087.38,0.104589]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(777, 23, 10, '[217,[9454.04,5261.97,0.00300598]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(778, 89, 10, '[199,[12525.9,11984,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(779, 89, 10, '[293,[9351.74,15258.9,0.00850677]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(780, 89, 10, '[310,[9251.79,2059.08,0.0140038]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(781, 89, 10, '[271,[16503.3,9805.29,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(782, 89, 10, '[219,[7489.96,8046.14,0.000335693]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(783, 89, 10, '[54,[9704.19,4731.92,0.0215988]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(784, 89, 10, '[273,[3503,7838.59,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(785, 47, 10, '[342,[2130.2,7102.84,0.0467148]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(786, 14, 10, '[1,[15129.4,9539.02,0.0100794]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(787, 10, 10, '[342,[2141.89,7102.96,0.0446053]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(788, 48, 10, '[343,[2137.76,7102.6,0.0414391]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(789, 12, 10, '[341,[2133.69,7103.56,0.0480652]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(790, 47, 10, '[342,[2126.66,7103.33,0.0381203]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(791, 10, 10, '[122,[1867.53,7180.35,0.0412025]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(792, 48, 10, '[91,[2236.42,7332.13,0.0434113]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(793, 12, 10, '[227,[1977.12,7314.2,0.0414314]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(794, 47, 10, '[325,[14276.1,11341.2,0.0357208]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(795, 10, 10, '[154,[17485.7,5878.32,0.0465851]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(796, 48, 10, '[90,[11995.8,14826.6,0.0642624]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(797, 12, 10, '[91,[12786.3,12594.9,0.0311279]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(798, 47, 10, '[294,[8427.57,3328.11,0.0574608]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(799, 10, 10, '[90,[5415.58,6186.02,0.0469246]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(800, 48, 10, '[339,[5298.04,8531.94,0.0501747]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(801, 12, 10, '[62,[4288.17,7869.8,0.0450974]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(802, 47, 10, '[293,[8058,6558.82,0.0485535]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(803, 10, 10, '[2,[16414,11521.6,0.0345001]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(804, 12, 10, '[91,[11200.6,15657.3,0.0419388]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(805, 47, 10, '[183,[16510.8,8259.83,0.0452576]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(806, 10, 10, '[79,[16100.5,14243.9,0.0524826]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(807, 48, 10, '[31,[15075.9,15924.6,0.0644913]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(808, 12, 10, '[90,[11175.4,15818.8,0.0353546]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(809, 47, 10, '[293,[15589.7,9072.52,0.0452518]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(810, 10, 10, '[91,[15733.3,9512.98,0.0452595]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(811, 48, 10, '[91,[14683.8,9881.79,0.0452595]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(812, 12, 10, '[315,[13419.4,8650.89,0.0454712]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(813, 47, 10, '[3,[14528.9,9956.16,0.0452671]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(814, 12, 10, '[91,[15001.5,9881.99,0.0452595]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(815, 14, 10, '[269,[5979.19,9939.29,0.0100784]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(816, 14, 10, '[318,[7468.45,4436.98,0.0100784]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(817, 14, 10, '[292,[4299.27,7984.63,0.00423813]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(818, 14, 10, '[293,[15248.2,9745.34,-0.0358782]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(819, 14, 10, '[293,[15493.8,9881.16,0.0145454]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(820, 14, 10, '[293,[9066.47,8118.34,0.0128784]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(821, 14, 10, '[273,[16184.7,10004.8,0.0109634]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(822, 14, 10, '[293,[17030.3,6246.27,0.0174866]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(823, 14, 10, '[293,[15270.5,9511.31,0.0100775]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(824, 14, 10, '[356,[16098.2,8204.98,0.125397]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(825, 14, 10, '[171,[16231.9,14855.5,0.0170135]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(826, 14, 10, '[359,[14889.9,17936.8,0.00637054]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(827, 14, 10, '[293,[1425.62,7193.55,0.0614738]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(828, 14, 10, '[294,[6193.01,1521.38,0.182577]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(829, 14, 10, '[171,[8537.62,20142.9,0.0104523]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(830, 14, 10, '[227,[14825.1,11901.1,0.0316849]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(831, 14, 10, '[221,[14642.6,12337.7,0.0271759]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(832, 14, 10, '[232,[16447.9,12912.2,0.032845]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(833, 14, 10, '[294,[8296.59,6950.21,0.253869]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(834, 14, 10, '[6,[6532.7,9966.24,0.0240402]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(835, 14, 10, '[340,[2123.28,7102.89,0.00970459]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(836, 65, 10, '[180,[16116.4,13812.2,-0.000217438]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(837, 65, 10, '[200,[17477.2,12276.4,0.0108566]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(838, 65, 10, '[324,[4629.23,8336.25,0.10837]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(839, 65, 10, '[273,[6671.33,8720.9,0.0102539]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(840, 65, 10, '[293,[7600.95,4315.18,-0.000370026]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(841, 65, 10, '[309,[9290.08,8222.67,-0.00038147]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(842, 65, 10, '[311,[10295.3,6320.12,0.0368347]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(843, 65, 10, '[126,[7805.89,9122.92,0.00511932]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(844, 65, 10, '[319,[8723.51,2986.67,0.00176048]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(845, 65, 10, '[94,[9381.76,4272.11,-0.000366211]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(846, 81, 10, '[266,[2160.29,7085.14,0.00204849]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(847, 81, 10, '[272,[2236.44,7065.34,0.00204086]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(848, 25, 10, '[144,[3722.14,2355.7,-0.544513]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(849, 25, 10, '[273,[11932.6,20890.1,-0.530017]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(850, 25, 10, '[179,[11920.5,20888.2,-0.55589]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(851, 82, 10, '[145,[15725.9,13419.4,0.0174866]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(852, 25, 10, '[85,[13425.4,4308.68,-0.535668]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(853, 25, 10, '[85,[13713.5,2884.49,-0.517073]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(854, 29, 10, '[185,[9694.08,4451.54,-0.00769806]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(855, 29, 10, '[340,[9697.81,4446.22,-0.00769806]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(856, 58, 10, '[155,[9885.42,3154.16,-0.00692749]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(857, 18, 10, '[110,[9887.89,3147.46,0.0118561]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(858, 7, 10, '[310,[9897.35,3145.53,0.00969696]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(859, 81, 10, '[345,[9900.03,3140.46,0.0110016]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(860, 26, 10, '[330,[8542.83,6953.21,-0.608744]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(861, 18, 10, '[90,[12262,15516.9,0]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(862, 9, 10, '[87,[12158.4,15170.1,0.00104523]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(863, 20, 10, '[90,[11822.1,15463.8,-0.00177765]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(864, 10, 10, '[90,[11954.3,15065.7,0.0534363]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(865, 25, 10, '[212,[10175.6,13971,-0.263998]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(866, 25, 10, '[159,[10558.2,13938.9,-0.592891]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(867, 25, 10, '[67,[10819.4,14116.8,-0.0761685]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(868, 25, 10, '[241,[9526.37,14832.4,-0.440026]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(869, 25, 10, '[281,[9509.38,14986.7,-0.416944]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(870, 88, 10, '[220,[7940.75,5388.84,0.0183563]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(871, 88, 10, '[135,[8950.19,3592.84,0.000854492]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(872, 91, 10, '[218,[7722.66,7858.29,-0.184998]]', '', '1.000', '0.34'),
(12993, 15, 10, '[0,[10196.053466797,18476.242675781,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(15151, 13067, 10, '[0,[16379.150390625,10297.104492188,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(15861, 23, 10, '[0,[15159.21875,7857.7124023438,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(16447, 15, 10, '[0,[17507.01171875,5292.0458984375,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(19428, 7, 10, '[0,[8469.7351074219,7728.5681152344,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(35837, 29, 10, '[0,[17196.274414062,7186.162109375,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(44465, 13067, 10, '[0,[13760.900878906,19245.368652344,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(49995, 5, 10, '[0,[10339.913330078,6864.736328125,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(50341, 23, 10, '[0,[7563.41796875,7817.5341796875,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(51506, 90, 10, '[0,[7517.3828125,7734.3078613281,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(64317, 36, 10, '[0,[14624.060058594,7800.3149414062,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(67914, 49784, 10, '[0,[17132.976074219,7748.6572265625,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(70566, 16306, 10, '[0,[7370.6457519531,7889.2810058594,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(71274, 23, 10, '[0,[13706.234130859,8348.4606933594,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(72159, 54, 10, '[0,[9839.2810058594,6104.2199707031,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(73714, 16306, 10, '[0,[6654.2236328125,8354.2004394531,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(95890, 90, 10, '[0,[6956.3293457031,8256.6247558594,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(95892, 90, 10, '[0,[16597.817382812,11192.504882812,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(95899, 15, 10, '[0,[16456.834716797,14309.187011719,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(95900, 6, 10, '[0,[13208.479003906,16656.743164062,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(95901, 25, 10, '[0,[1423.4790039062,13875.836181641,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99271, 23, 10, '[0,[10604.615478516,6465.8239746094,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99277, 30, 10, '[0,[8207.91015625,5016.5380859375,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99279, 8, 10, '[0,[15150.587158203,7857.7124023438,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99280, 53, 10, '[0,[14488.831787109,10630.009765625,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99281, 53, 10, '[0,[9879.5617675781,7358.3544921875,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99282, 53, 10, '[0,[9338.6486816406,4640.5847167969,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99285, 5, 10, '[0,[10337.036132812,6870.4760742188,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99286, 6, 10, '[0,[9655.1403808594,7653.9514160156,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99287, 8, 10, '[0,[8121.5942382812,8377.1594238281,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99288, 6, 10, '[0,[14252.901611328,7920.849609375,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99290, 16, 10, '[0,[16615.080566406,12544.215087891,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99291, 16, 10, '[0,[13389.742431641,12900.079345703,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99292, 16, 10, '[0,[12719.35546875,13772.520751953,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99294, 6, 10, '[0,[10256.474609375,19397.471923828,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99295, 6, 10, '[0,[8774.7180175781,20579.859619141,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99296, 19, 10, '[0,[8058.2958984375,21024.689941406,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99298, 16, 10, '[0,[12975.426025391,14636.352539062,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99299, 16, 10, '[0,[12454.653320312,14886.031494141,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99300, 15, 10, '[0,[15757.67578125,14277.618408203,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99301, 15, 10, '[0,[15242.657470703,17118.792724609,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99302, 16, 10, '[0,[15205.25390625,16909.291992188,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99303, 10, 10, '[0,[12670.443115234,19268.327636719,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99304, 23, 10, '[0,[7321.7333984375,9482.060546875,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99305, 16, 10, '[0,[5736.3977050781,9510.7592773438,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99306, 90, 10, '[0,[9715.5615234375,7493.2385253906,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
(99307, 90, 10, '[0,[15398.026123047,8147.5695800781,0]]', '', '1.000', ''),
```

- cut - - full here: http://pastebin.com/rpWUzqMj

  --

  ### -- Constraints for dumped tables

  --

  ### -- Constraints for table `world_vehicle`

  ALTER TABLE `world_vehicle`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `world_vehicle_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `vehicle` (`id`),
    ADD CONSTRAINT `world_vehicle_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`world_id`) REFERENCES `world` (`id`);

  /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
  /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
  /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;

After importing this, I get this error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I don't understand how I could have a dupe error if this was working in the old database.
So I tried just inserting the main id's and I got this:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`user-####`.`world_vehicle`, CONSTRAINT `world_vehicle_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicle_id`) REFERENCES `vehicle` (`id`))
```

Please help me guys, this is really bugging me and I need these database's moved.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but better than never...?

What's going on with the **#1062 error** and I've experienced as funky errors when importing before, is that an A_I (auto-incremented) column might create an additional "1" entry on import. This is generally due to something going into the table prior to import and creating a new record. The solution to this, regardless, is to go into the table operations and reset your AUTO_INCREMENT count value to "0". Then you should be able to import without issue.

If that fails, then it's a needle/haystack scenario looking through the dump of the old database to find the duplicate value. Though both values should be right at the beginning of the dumps. From there you'll have to figure out how to handle this, but it would mean somebody likely did A_I on the column, but failed to make it a UNIQUE value, and had already inserted a "1" to test.

What's going on with your **#1452 error** is that your child table, the one you're trying to create a relation with doesn't have an existing, matching value. So you need to import the parent table in full prior to importing the child table and/or making the relation.